# Wordpress posts count with comman tags within specific category

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

i have two categories 'A' and 'B'. Both have 5 posts(each) with tag 'C'. How i can display the number of posts as 5 in Category 'A' or 'B' page. It showing total number of post with tag 'C' as 10. I need to show it as 5. How i can pass category variable to display exact count with tag within specific category. Here is my current code:

```
$tag = get_term_by('name', $tags,'post_tag');
$count = $tag->count;
```

reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the `get_term_by()` method.

Try this:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND', // only posts that have both taxonomies will return.
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field'    => 'name',
      'terms'    => 'TAG_C', // you can also use an array with tags.
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => 'CATEGORY_B', // you can also use an array with categories.
    ),
  ),
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
$count = count($posts);
```

> I haven't tested this code, but it should work. Ofcourse you do have
>   to set the correct terms.

---

**UPDATE**

When dealing with many posts I would create a `$wpdb` sql query that counts the rows, so only a number is returned and not all the posts. You can find an sql count example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131687/how-to-return-number-of-found-rows-from-select-query).

Comment: Thanks, but it will increase cpu load. I have around 100000 posts.

Comment: Well this is the fastest because it's a single query. 100k posts is alot, but i think it will be fast enough, ofcourse it also depends on the server you're running this.

Comment: Bjorn, anyway I'm not sure it is the best solution. Just imagine how much memory your server will need to keep an array with about 20-30 thousand of posts...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "found_posts" property of the WP_Query class object.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'category_name'   => 'aaa', // category slug
    'tag'             => 'ccc'  // tag slug
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "Total posts count: ".$wp_query->found_posts;
```